# Python regex to remove all occurances of [Number]

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for the regex statement in python that will remove all occurances of [1] or [17] or basically [*] from a string. The occurances are as follows where * equals some number:

```
[*]
[ * ]
[ *]
[* ]
```

Currently I have:

```
re.sub(r'\[*\]', '', origional_string)
```

Which raises `invalid expression`

Example input string:

```
makeup of organisms.[10] In 1997, while working at the University of Tennessee, Pigliucci received the Theodosius Dobzhansky Prize,[11]
```

Expected output:

```
makeup of organisms. In 1997, while working at the University of Tennessee, Pigliucci received the Theodosius Dobzhansky Prize,
```

Comment: you probably want `r'\[.*\]'`

Comment: also, tested you code, no `invalid expression` here.

Comment: While *you* might choose to represent "some number" by `*`, in python regular expressions, `*` means "match 0 or more occurrences of the previous expression". This means that `\[*\]` translates to: match 0 or more `[` and then match 1 `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like that should work:

```
import re

origional_string = "makeup of organisms.[10] In 1997, while working at the University of Tennessee, Pigliucci received the Theodosius Dobzhansky Prize,[11]"

result = re.sub(r'\[ *[0-9]+ *\]', '', origional_string)

print(result)
```

`[0-9]+` matches one or more digits, while  `*` matches spaces if any.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/SCducf)

Answer (score 0):

`\d` means digit in regex. And I have also added option `\s` around the digits here.

```
re.sub(r'\[\s*\d+\s*\]', '', origional_string)
```

Comment: not actually working. I have included an example original string

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> import re
 >>> re.sub(r'\[\s*\d+\s*\]', '', original_string)
```

Comment: I don't want to replace all digits as shown in the new included example

Comment: @MattStokes I had thought your input was only square brackets and number and goal was to remove numbers within square brackets. I see that it is different than my expectation with new example so updated for it.